# iOS Swift and reloadRowsAtIndexPaths compilation error

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, reload

I've hit deadlock with xCode/Swift and refreshing a single row of UITableView.

This line works....

```
self.tableView.reloadData();
```

whereas this line doesn't

```
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([_currentIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None);
```

Auto-complete is suggesting *reloadRowsAtIndexPaths* and giving the syntax but on compilation, I'm getting the error:

> 'Could not find member 'reloadRowsAtIndexPaths'.

If I right click and '`jump to definition`' in `self.tableview`, the symbol is not found.

I'm hoping I'm not doing anything embarrassingly stupid here and would appreciate help. I could use `reloadData` but want to know why this isn't working here.

Comment: I use it exactly as you want to do it: `self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)` without problems.

Comment: ...reassuring. It's an odd one!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe, `_currentIndexPath` is Optional. something like

```
var _currentIndexPath:NSIndexPath?
```

So try:

```
if let indexPath = _currentIndexPath {
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
}
else {
    // `_currentIndexPath` is nil.
    // Error handling if needed.
}
```

Comment: #rintaro.  Thanks...works perfectly. So my next question is...why?

Comment: What would be the ideal place to put this in. Would it be here ...
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { ....
OR in viewDidAppear() etc